# How to extract or split some days from date when date is index or string?

Tags: python

I have 6000 rows and 8 columns, where 'Date' is like index or I can reset index and it would be like first column with string type. I need to Extract the list of 'Lake_Level' values where date of a record is second and seventh day of a month ( and provide top 3 and bottom 3 values of the 'Lake_Level' feature). Please show me how to make it. Thank you in advance.

```py
      Date  Loc_1  Loc_2  Loc_3  Loc_4  Loc_5   Temp  Lake_Level  Flow_Rate
03/06/2003    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      249.43       0.31
04/06/2003    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      249.43       0.31
05/06/2003    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      249.43       0.31
06/06/2003    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      249.43       0.31
07/06/2003    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      249.43       0.31
26/06/2021    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  22.50      250.85       0.60
27/06/2021    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  23.40      250.84       0.60
28/06/2021    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  21.50      250.83       0.60
29/06/2021    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  23.20      250.82       0.60
30/06/2021    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  22.75      250.80       0.60
```

Comment: hi, please add example data

Comment: It's in the top named DATA, above Hello.

Comment: no images please - text so we can reproduce your issue

Comment: I hope it is understandable

Comment: thats better. For reference, you can use `df.to_dict()` to capture the dtypes as well, and will get the best response if you post the exact dataframe you expect to output (makes it easy to verify logic matches desired logic)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just filter rows with your ideal condition?

You can run queries on your dataset using pandas `DataFrame` like below:

If datetimes are in column

```py
df[pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.day.isin([2,7])]
```

If datetimes are as indexes

```py
df[pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True).day.isin([2,7])]
```

Here is an example:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:     'Date': [random_date() for _ in range(100)],
   ...:     'Lake_Level': [random.randint(240, 260) for _ in range(100)]
   ...: })

In [3]: df[pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.day.isin([2,7])]
Out[3]: 
          Date  Lake_Level
2   07/08/2004         245
27  02/12/2017         249
30  02/06/2012         252
51  07/10/2013         257
```

Comment: I tried this, bus I see now my mistake, thank you !

Comment: Yw. Mark my answer as the solution, please.

Comment: I marked . Maybe you can also help how to Predict water level (7d, 28d)? its seems difficult because of date being index.

Comment: You should ask your different questions in different threads.